# ANFIS with caret package

Tags: r, prediction, r-caret

I have a large data frame and I want to predict one variable (column) with the ANFIS model (and more specifically with `caret` package). The goal is to perform a 10-k cross validation. Until now I have the following:

```
    # my example dataframe from frbs package

    m=diamonds[1:100,-(2:4)]
    m$k=m$carat*-0.1
    m$l=m$x *-0.1
    m$n=m$depth*2.3 


# train - test 
d.train <- m[1 : 72, ]
d.test <- m[73 : 100, 1 : 9]

# the range of my data
m.range=apply(m,2,range)
# method,type,control 
meth.type <- "ANFIS"
cont = list(num.labels = 10, max.iter = 100, step.size = 0.01, type.tnorm = "MIN", type.snorm = "MAX", type.implication.func = "ZADEH", name = "dmn")
# the model 
an_md <- frbs.learn(d.train, m.range, meth.type, cont)

# predict
r.tst <- predict(an_md, d.test)
```

Sorry if my question is simple or my way of reproduction is not very good, but here are my questions:

a. with the code above I get as prediction a column with one value (152.4900). What is wrong (perhaps the columns with negative values)?

b. How to add the `max.iter` parameter in caret to perform the k-fold? (example with caret below):

```
con = trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
for_train = createDataPartition(m$n, p=.70, list=FALSE) 
train=m[for_train,] 
test=m[-for_train,] 
model = train(n ~., data = train, method = "ANFIS", trControl = con)
```

Any suggestions to solve this or make my question better, are welcomed.